# Marker interface in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, attributes, marker-interfaces

I am currently trying to implement a marker interface in c#. But I haven't done this so far so I'd like to ask you for advice please.

Short my problem:
I've a interface Factory, and the factory contains several subinterface which should be marker interface because they don't have a property or method or something. So the marker interface should implement the interface factory. And my marker interface is for example for Cars, Trucks etc. And the marker interface is implemented for Cars for MyBMW, MyAUDI etc. How can I implement such a pattern? Thanks!

```
interface Factory
{
    string[] process (string [] entry);
}
```

Comment: You have not posted a marker interface. It has a method. A marker interface has **nothing** to implement.

Comment: I think rather than deciding on the solution and asking on how, we can better help if you present the problem and we see if marker interface is useful at all.

Comment: Yes, but Car, Trucks and Bus should use the interface Factory but Car, Truck and Bus don't have any methods because MyBMW, and MyAUDI should implement the marker interface Car and they have the necessary methods included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about using Attributes instead of interface to mark classes.

then you can decide in your code how to handle specific instances as the attribute is set.

Comment: I still prefer interfaces. Attributes have their place, but marker interfaces 'feel' better.

Comment: An attribute applied to a class will not generally affect any derived classes (it's possible for code which would check an attribute in a class to check the attribute for parent classes as well).  By contrast, if a class implements a marker interface, all derived classes will do so as well.  If one wants to force derived classes to advertise a characteristic, use a marker interface.  If one wants to allow a derived class to decide whether or not to advertise a characteristic, use attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to implent the factory pattern. I suggest you to look an example here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern